# Routing for private EC2 instances behind Load Balancers in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-vpc

I have 4 EC2 instances, 2 in the private subnet of each availability zone (2AZs), one hosting App A and the other hosting AppB. The instances are behind 2 internet-facing ALBs (one ALB for each app), with route 53 routing the traffic to the corresponding ALB based on the sub-domain name, and 2 NAT Gateways in each public subnet routing internet traffic for the private instances.

I want appA and AppB to communicate using HTTPs using the domain name of each app.
Will the traffic for each Application come from the load balancer? Since each EC2 instance allows the traffic only from the security group of its ALB.
Should the security group for each app allow the traffic from the other or the traffic will come from the load balancer?
I have DNS resolution activated for the VPC.

Answer (score 2):

For traffic within the setup you've described the ingress traffic for the domains will enter through the load balancer which will then forward the requests to the EC2 instance(s). As long as the load balancers security group allows the inbound traffic you will receive the traffic.

For egress traffic for your application it will depend on both your EC2 and routing configuration.

If your EC2 instance resides within a public subnet (and has a public IP address) then the EC2 will route traffic via the [internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html). If your EC2 instance is in a private subnet you will need to use either a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) to route traffic to the internet.

These options will be configured within the [route table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) for the subnet(s) that are applicable, in addition the outbound security group rules for your EC2 instance will need to allow access to the destination ip, port and protocol that you want. By default the security group will allow all outbound access.

Comment: I already have a public subnet in each AZ with a NAT Gateway routing the traffic to the internet. The outbound traffic for each EC2 allows all outbound traffic. The security group of the ALBs allows inbound traffic on port 443 only for HTTPS with HTTP redirects enabled.

Comment: If the subnets are using a NAT Gateway then they will be private subnets :) Traffic would route through the NAT Gateway and the other application would receive inbound traffic from the NAT Gateways IP

Comment: I didn't get what you mean? The NAT Gateways are placed in the public subnets, the EC2 instances are in private subnets, with the internet traffic routed to the NAT gateways. My concern is about the traffic from each instance, i need to allow traffic from each application over HTTPS

Comment: Right I see what you mean, the EC2s security group just needs to allow HTTPS outbound, with the destination allowing inbound traffic from the NAT gateways elastic IP

Comment: Currently, the security group of each ALB allows only internet traffic to each EC2 instance. So should I update the inbound rules for the Security groups of the EC2 instances or the load balancer? Does the internal traffic leave the VPC from one instance to the other? I want to restrict access to each EC2 from it's load balancer's sec group

Comment: If your instance is connecting to a host name that resolves to the load balancer, it will be the destination load balancers security group that needs to allow inbound access.